# Change Transition Duration on click of movieclip Flash AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5, transition

I have a movieclip with instance name spaceship. On click of this movieclip i want to change the speed of transition. Here's my code :

```
import fl.transitions.*;
import fl.transitions.easing.*; 

var myspaceship:TransitionManager = new TransitionManager(spaceship);
myspaceship.startTransition({type:Fly, direction:Transition.OUT, duration:18,startPoint:6});
spaceship.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, speedfast);
function speedfast (evt:MouseEvent):void
{
// reset frame count to 0
//here i want the duration to become say 12 or something
}
```

That is I want the spaceship to speed up on mouseclick...

Comment: I'd suggest using [Greensock TweenMax](http://greensock.com), which will ease your pain while animating.

Answer (score 0):

#### Update

```
var myspaceship:TransitionManager = new TransitionManager(spaceship);
var speed:int = 18;

myspaceship.startTransition(
    {type:Fly, direction:Transition.OUT, duration: speed,startPoint:6}
);

spaceship.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, speedfast);
function speedfast (evt:MouseEvent):void {
   // reset frame count to 0
   trace("Increase Speed");
   speed -= 6;
   trace("Duration of transition: " + speed);
   //Start transition
   trace("Start transition");
   myspaceship.startTransition(
    {type:Fly, direction:Transition.OUT, duration: speed,startPoint:6}
   );
   //or speed = 12;
   //or better speed = speed / 2;
}
```

Comment: Does your spaceship was moving first place? I just showing you the logic. If you reduce the duration of the transition,then the speed of the spaceship will increase.

Comment: yes it moves. all i want to do is increase the speed on touch.

Comment: @Bhaijaan Have you restart the transition to see if the duration is been reduced?